# Custom vocabularies for Speech Recognition in Windows

Tags: windows, speech-recognition

Using Windows7 speech recognition I wish to create specialised vocabularies for recognising a domain-specific natural language in parts of my application. Thus, for example, a specific text entry box could be linked to its own vocabulary and limited to a small subset of language, e.g.

```
throw the axe at the troll
```

where `"troll"` is in the vocabulary but `"trawl"` is not. The application should be able to learn, so:

```
throw the axe at the arggly
```

should allow `"arggly"` to be spelt out and recognised and added to the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how you're implementing the speech recognition.  If you're using SAPI directly, I'd look at implementing an [application lexicon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717919(VS.85).aspx).  If you're assuming that WSR is providing the recognition, and you want your WSR to magically discover your new vocabularies, then that's going to be a fair bit harder.

In particular, you need to set up an [input scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms629026(VS.85).aspx), and pass IS_PHRASELIST and IS_DEFAULT (along with your custom phrases).  Also note that you have to remove the input scope before the window gets destroyed.